# Expandable items not visible to Accessibility in Android

Tags: android, accessibility

I have an expandable list and when I am expanding a row, the children of the parent  view are not visible to accessibility and therefore when swiping in order to move to the child view the accessibility focus moves to the next parent item instead.
I'm using NodeTreeDebug:

The item in red is the parent and items in blue are the children. Please note that all the children are invisible [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UxQg.png)
The same here but this time all children are visible and 
I can go through them with the accessibility TalkBack. The weird thing is that in order to achieve the children visibility I scroll a bit the list, very weird [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyeD1.png)

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/pale_grey_two"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="end">

        <requestFocus />

        <com.ngsoft.discount_business.ui.views.textViews.DiscountFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
            android:text="פקדונות"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size4"
            app:customFont="@string/rubik_regular" />


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the children layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/itemFullLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/down_arrow_icon" />


     <com.ngsoft.discount_business.ui.views.textViews.DiscountFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="פקדונות"
            android:textColor="@color/slate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size5"
            app:customFont="@string/rubik_regular" />


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is the parent layout

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code. It's very difficult to diagnose a problem without it. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, more details needed.  Also, does the example work on iOS?  What about screen readers on the desktop (JAWS (PC), NVDA (PC), VoiceOver (Mac))?  Are the list children focusable elements (can you get to them using TAB  on the keyboard)?

Comment: edited my question